# in C++11 should functions that return a temp return const or non const

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Before move constructors if you returned a temp it was a best practice to have it return const to avoid having somebody assign to the temp variable

Now it seems with move constructors not working on const returns, it would seem that not returning const would be best practice

But, now you are back to the problem of somebody legally assigning to temp variables

Quick example (assume a very expensive copy constuctor):

```
MyClass a=1;
MyClass b=2;

(a+b)=3;  // how do I disallow this and allow move constuctors for `operator+`
```

if `operator+` returns `const MyClass` then it that will not compile, but any regular useage would use the expensive copy constructor instead of the cheap move constuctor.

Comment: Why is that a problem, exactly? It seems highly unlikely that someone would write a fragment like this unintentionally, by mistake. I don't think it's worth going out of one's way to make this not compile.

Comment: IMHO, Any little thing that we can get the compiler to enforce for us is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You avoid assignment to rvalues by constraining assignment operators to only work on lvalues:

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass& operator = (const MyClass& other) & {
    // ...
    return *this;
  }
  MyClass& operator = (MyClass&& other) & {
    // ...
    return *this;
  }
  // or, ideally:
  MyClass& operator = (const MyClass& other) & = default;
  MyClass& operator = (MyClass&& other) & = default;
};
```

Ref-qualifiers were added to C++11 late, so compiler support has only started to appear recently.

Comment: Although in this case it's implicit, it might be good to also explicitly delete the rvalue versions of the `operator=`s.

Comment: what does the lvalue version look like? (just omit the &)?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum That *is* the lvalue version - member functions with a single `&` ref-qualifer will be preferred by the compiler when calling with an lvalue object. Member functions with a double `&&` ref-qualifer will be preferred by the compiler when calling with an rvalue object. It's just like the distinction between `const` and non-`const` member functions. [citation needed]

Comment: So: `op=()` is for both | `op=() &` is for lvalue | `op=() &&` is for rvalue, and would be similar in contract to a move constructor in that it should reset the rhs, and therefore can shallow copy?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Given `T t; U u;`, `t = u;` will call `T::op=(const U&)&` if exists, or `T::op=(const U&)` otherwise. `std::move(t) = u;` will call `T::op=(const U&)&&` if it exists, or `T::op=(const U&)` otherwise. The reference qualifier constrains the acceptable value category of the object to which `this` points, much like the way a `const` or `volatile` qualifier on a member function constrains the `const` qualification of the object pointed at by `this`.

Comment: So if both `op=&` and `op=&&` exist then `op=` cannot be called but it legal to also define `op=`, and if `op=&` or `op=&&` esists, then the other 2 will implicitely not exist?